# UK Bank holidays JSON read into Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to read this JSON file into pandas but I'm not able to read it properly :

https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json

i've tried to use json_normalize to change this as well as opening this first as a file with the standard python library, changing to dict and reading it into pandas as a dict.

this is what I'm getting at the moment :

```
        body    content_id  description divisions.england-and-wales.2012    divisions.england-and-wales.2013    divisions.england-and-wales.2014    divisions.england-and-wales.2015    divisions.england-and-wales.2016    divisions.england-and-wales.2017    divisions.england-and-wales.2018    ... divisions.scotland.2015 divisions.scotland.2016 divisions.scotland.2017 divisions.scotland.2018 divisions.scotland.2019 divisions.scotland.2020 divisions.scotland.slug divisions.scotland.title    need_id title
0       58f79dbd-e57f-4ab2-ae96-96df5767d1b2    bank_holidays.calendar.description  [{'title': 'bank_holidays.new_year', 'date': '...   [{'title': 'bank_holidays.new_year', 'date': '...   [{'title': 'bank_holidays.new_year', 'date': '...   [{'title': 'bank_holidays.new_year', 'date': '...   [{'title': 'bank_holidays.new_year', 'date': '...   [{'title': 'bank_holidays.new_year', 'date': '...   [{'title': 'bank_holidays.new_year', 'date': '...   ... [{'title': 'bank_holidays.new_year', 'date': '...   [{'title': 'bank_holidays.new_year', 'date': '...   [{'title': 'bank_holidays.2nd_january', 'date'...   [{'title': 'bank_holidays.new_year', 'date': '...   [{'title': 'bank_holidays.new_year', 'date': '...   [{'title': 'bank_holidays.new_year', 'date': '...   common.nations.scotland_slug    common.nations.scotland 100128  bank_holidays.calendar.title
```

is anyone able to help?

Ive tried all the orient options in Pandas but I'm still none-the-wiser.

due to being behind a complicated proxy I have to save this file down from the website but I don't think that's the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you have already managed to load the linked JSON into a dictionary, I'm going to skip that step meaning that my code begins with all of the data already stored in dictionary `d`.

To store this in a sensible format, I would recommend looping over the three sub dictionaries for the three different countries, create a DataFrame for each, then finally concatenate the three DataFrames using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for country, data in d.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['events'])
    df['Country'] = country
    dfs.append(df)

final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This looks really smart, will test as soon as I'm home!

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks for all your help, I still have a long way to go!

Answer (score 1):

You can just from_dict

```
import requests
import lxml
from lxml import html
import pandas as pd
import json

url = "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json"

r = requests.get(url)
d = r.json()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
print(df)
```